# Error:(27, 13) Failed to resolve: com.github.jiahuanyu:PopSeekbar:0.2.3

Tags: android, seekbar

i am getting the above error while importing the library from **`"compile 'com.github.jiahuanyu:PopSeekbar:0.2.3'"`** this dependency,

error:

```
Error:(27, 13) Failed to resolve: com.github.jiahuanyu:PopSeekbar:0.2.3
<a href="openFile">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

i am struck with this, please help me...

My build.gradle content.

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.admin.shopunter_user"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

repositories {

```
jcenter()

maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
```

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'

compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'

compile 'org.immutables:gson:2.1.0.alpha'

compile 'com.h6ah4i.android.widget.verticalseekbar:verticalseekbar:0.5.2'

compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'

compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'

compile 'com.github.jiahuanyu:PopSeekbar:0.2.3'

compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
compile 'cz.msebera.android:httpclient:4.3.6'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Just add this in your **build.gradle**

```
dependencies {

       compile 'com.github.jiahuanyu:PopSeekbar:0.2.3'

    }
```

Then

**`Build > Clean Project Then Build > Rebuild Project`**

Then Click **Invalidate Caches/Restart Options** And **Do Gradle (Sync)**

Answer (score 0):

I add this to buildscript{} to solve the problem.

```html
allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }
```